# How can I send email from my application?

Tags: cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I want to attach a video and send email from my application.
 I downloaded apples example code  MailComposer. I compiled it. I did not get any errors or warnings.
 I sent the mail to my mail id. But, I could not see any mail in my inbox. I am working on simulator.
 I did not set any senders email id in simulator. 
How can I know whether the code is working or not ?
Thank You.

Comment: Try testing on the device, and see if it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simulator cannot send email; nor can all devices, as you'll discover if you use the `MFMailComposeViewController` `+canSendMail` method—it returns `NO` if the device doesn't have a mail account set up. To quote the documentation:

> You should call this method before attempting to display the mail composition interface. If it returns NO, you must not display the mail composition interface.

Comment: Thank You.
So, you mean we can't send email from simulator. So, I have to check in device. I will add canSendMail method to my program and then check it.